# Site URL parameter: http vs https

Tags: facebook, fb.ui

I'm running into an issue that's arising from the fact that one has to either chose http or https as the scheme in the Site URL parameter in settings for a Facebook app.

Upon invoking FB.ui, the SDK takes it upon itself to send an "origin" parameter which has the domain of the current page. If this origin domain doesn't match the Site URl parameter in app settings, it throws an "invalid redirect uri" error. The page we're invoking on is not secure (http), but our Site URL is set up as https because we use FB connect on our secure login pages (https).

We want to avoid the overhead of having to make these extraneous FB.ui pages https as well, but as far as we've seen we cannot specify multiple Site Urls (to account for both http and https).

Is there a good solution to this? Perhaps a way to "block" or modify the origin parameter FB.ui sends?

Comment: is this a canvas app, mobile app, or app with FB login?

Comment: Just a straight-up app. We do have iOS/Android mobile apps but everything is fine with those. This issue is on the desktop/non-mobile version of our web app

Comment: when you make a canvas desktop app. You specify it when making, you are given the option to declare both http and https urls.

Comment: This is not a canvas app...it's a normal fb app

Comment: When you create an app, you have 6 choices. 3 mobile options and 3 desktop options. Of the 3 desktop options website with FB login, App on Facebook or Page tab. which one is it?

Comment: Ok I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at and this app was created a long time ago so not sure. What I can tell you is that under basic app settings, "Select how your app integrates with Facebook", we have the following options set up: "Website with Facebook Login", "Mobile Web" (site url is specified under these two), and native iOS and Android apps. "App on Facebook" and "Page Tab" are NOT enabled.

Comment: you can set both a http and https url with app on facebook.

Comment: Ok I see that, but App on Facebook has nothing to do with FB.ui does it? In other words, adding http and https under App on Facebook will have no effect on the issue I'm describing right?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see, and you will need to make all pages that interact with Facebook https, canvas apps automatically redirect to https.

Comment: Wow entirely unexpected but that fixed it! Thanks a lot Chamilyan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also programmaticly set the parameters for a secue canvas URL via REST or Open Graph API.

**property** `secure_canvas_url`

REST - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appproperties/

Open Graph - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#props

Note the following regarding HTTPS on FBML applications

***FBML apps***

> We have heard that there is some confusion about whether FBML apps
>   must support HTTPS. FBML developers still need to know whether users
>   are browsing Facebook over a secure connection since they need to
>   detect whether to serve iframe or video content over HTTPS. As a
>   result, FBML apps must obtain SSL certificates in order to serve this
>   type of content to users browsing over a secure connection. If you
>   have an FBML app, please obtain an SSL certificate for your app to
>   receive traffic from users browsing Facebook over a secure connection.
>
> If you enable SSL for your FBML app, please make sure that your SSL
>   certificate includes all intermediate certificates in the chain of
>   trust as our SSL validation is strict. You can use third-party SSL
>   analysis tools (e.g., https://www.ssllabs.com/index.html) to check
>   your certificate status and fix any errors (and warnings). If your SSL
>   certificate has problems, you may see "Empty response received" error
>   when you load your FBML canvas app.

See the following for a complete description

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/567/

Before all else fails , check mark your app as a canvas application in application settings (even if it is not technically a canvas app). And set an https url. This may solve any https related issue before having to address it programmaticly.